# Как лучше организовать обмен аудиоконтентом?

Tags: javascript, websocket, аудио, web-audio

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо получать от пользователя ввод голосовых команд, затем эти команды обрабатываются на backend, после чего пользователю возвращается ответ в аудио формате.

Принимаю аудио от пользователя при помощи [annyang](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang), а на backend отдаю уже готовый текст. Эта штука хорошо работает, но не во всех браузерах ( в частности в firefox - нет)

Затем полученный текст после ряда преобразований отправляю в [Watson](https://www.ibm.com/watson/), и оттуда при помощи [text to speach](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/), получаю аудиофайл, который и воспроизвожу в браузере.

Всё вроде бы нормально, но `autoplay` в `<audio>` не работает на мобильных браузерах, и мне кажется не очень правильным работа через `POST/GET`, как это делается сейчас.

Как правильно организовать взаимодействие клиента и сервера в моей ситуации ?

Задача, чтобы человек задавал вопрос, и получал нужный ему ответ, чтобы это было максимально быстро и кроссбраузерно.

Сейчас есть неизбежная задержка на сервере, так как данные отдаются в несколько сервисов, прежде чем отдать ответ, но с этим ещё можно разобраться.

Но что сделать с воспроизведением аудио файла в мобильных браузерах ?
Вообще, идея воспроизведения аудио файла кажется чуть чуть глупой.

Буду крайне благодарен за любую наводку в правильном направлении.

Заранее спасибо!